# How do I create a vba module that will highlight two columns that are not next to one another based on the header name

Tags: vba, excel

New to this, but right now I need to sort lots of pages of data, I would love to be able to highlight two specific columns based on the header name. Right now I have this which I found online, which is fine, aside from the fact that I have to search for two different columns. any help would be appreciated

```
Sub FindAddressColumn()

   'Updateby Extendoffcie

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xRgUni As Range
    Dim xFirstAddress As String
    Dim xStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xStr = "Name"
    Set xRg = Range("A1:P1").Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
        Do
            Set xRg = Range("A1:P1").FindNext(xRg)
            If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
                Set xRgUni = xRg
            Else
                Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
            End If
        Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
    End If
    xRgUni.EntireColumn.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Will the searched column names appear only once per worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong order of commands. You overwrite xRg  with `.FindNext` before unioning. Try this way:

```
 If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
    xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
    Do
        ' Set xRg = Range("A1:P1").FindNext(xRg)   --- moved below
        If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
            Set xRgUni = xRg
        Else
            Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
        End If
        Set xRg = Range("A1:P1").FindNext(xRg)   ' --- moved here
    Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
End If
```